# How to assign content to user for manage turns?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, datetime

I need to create a system to assign turns to a people register in the site, for this need contemplate:

1. The administer assign turn to user in specified place.ex(turn 1, place 1, user 1)
2. There are two turns, morning and afternoon in one day.(turn 1 and turn 2)
3. The administer cannot assign a turn to user that have turn 1 in place 1 and later turn 1 in place 2, need show only the users that no have turn 1.
4. The system need show the turn to user in calendar, only need show the turns in the week, ex (Monday: turn 1 place 1, Tuesday: turn 2 place2, Wednesday: turn 3 place 3, etc).

I think make

content type of turns that have

```
- field date, end and start for statistics support and classify the week.
- turn select: turn 1 or turn 2.
- zones select: place 1, place 2, place3 etc.
- user to assign: user reference field that have all user that i can assign turns.
```

I want use drupal fields and contrib modules (if exist) to make this, or how to make better with drupal, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module for this. [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various roles and permissions, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: i try to use but no wroking for that i need

Comment: @jonathan : can you be more specific about the "no working"? Why not, what is missing, etc?