# How to Create Membership Groups for Products?

Tags: 7, commerce, organic-groups

I'm exploring if the latest release of Drupal Commerce (using Commerce Kickstart 7x-2.38) will work for my Apparel eCommerce requirements. We need membership to groups (which will be corporate accounts or schools) that will present authenticated users a selection of apparel products using corporate or school logos and of course special pricing. I've looked into both Organic Groups and Membership Entities and neither seem to be the best solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to look at is the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which is an alternative to [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) ...

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various roles and permissions, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll check this module out.

Comment: @AndrewWolfe : OK ... expect the unexpected in doing so ... Please get back with your feedback about it afterwards