# How to implement something to differentiate nodes?

Tags: 7, users

I wonder how I could implement something in my Drupal site where nodes can be different and managed separately.

For example, in my site I want to add to nodes as shops, and every vendor must manage his/her shop, post news, add images, etc.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for sure, use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module for this. [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various roles and permissions, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".