# How to assign roles to grant permissions to update particular pages?

Tags: 7, users

I have a menu like Publications, About us , Services and i want to assign a roles to the users like one user can update the content of about us and other can services means need to give permission for specific pages.

Is this is possible?

Some more details about what I'm trying to do: I do not want to give the permission to whole content type (that is not required). I want a user wise permissions like I have a role named ***ouroffice-user***. Then under this I have a 10 users and I want to allocate different permissions to these 10 users like no. 1 have a permission to update the `welcome` content and no. 2 have a permission to update the `about us` page all users belong to single role that ouroffice-user.

Comment: Please check my edit of your question, to integrate your comment and improve the title. Feel free to further refine or improve it. If you don't like my edit just perform a rollback, ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections.

**Group** creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it. Groups can also act as a parent of any type of entity. Group provides an extensive API to attach entities to groups.

For way more details about this module, such as how to configure it or available integrations with other modules, refer to my answer to "[What are the alternatives for the Organic groups module?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/164?s=da&i=221130)".

For this specific question you'd only need 1 Group *Type*, with 1 Group (of that Group Type) for each set (= collection) of "*Specific Pages*" (as in your question). BTW, available for either D7 or D8.

Have a look at the Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s&app=desktop)". Even though it is about D8 (already), the key concepts of it are the same as in the D7 version. Maybe also review the answers to various questions around here tagged with the [group](/questions/tagged/group) tag.

Some more details about this part of your question:

> Some more details about what I'm trying to do: I do not want to give the permission to whole content type (that is not required). I want a user wise permissions like I have a role named ouroffice-user. Then under this I have a 10 users and I want to allocate different permissions to these 10 users like no. 1 have a permission to update the welcome content and no. 2 have a permission to update the about us page all users belong to single role that ouroffice-user.

- Be aware that "roles" in the Group module are different from the typical (standard) roles in Drupal. For more details about the various roles and permissions that can be configured, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".
- Assume you create a custom Group role like "content manager". And you allow members with this group role to **edit** nodes of content type ABC.
- From those 10 users (in your comment), those that correspond to your "no 1" should become members of some group (say titled **Group no 1**), in which they receive access to that Group role "content manager". And assume you create a similar group titled **Group no 2**, for those that correspond to your "no 2" users.
- Using the `gnode` submodule you assign the nodes such as `Welcome` to the **Group no 1** group and `About us` is assigned to the **Group no 2** group. Note that it doesn't matter what the content types are (if they are the same or not), which is part of the beauty of the Group module.

Done ... really! Give it a try to get the idea ... those who try, love it ... after they get it ...

Comment: @its give the permission to whole content type but that is not required.
 
i want a user wise permissions like i have a role name ouroffice-user then under this i have a 10 users and i want to allocate different different permissions to these 10 users like no. 1 have a permission to update the welcome content and no. 2 have a permission to update the about us page all users belong to single role that ouroffice-user

Comment: @SumitAggarwal : any further feedback about my answer? Also, I noticed that you posted 3 new questions ater this one, 2 of them on hold already (be carefull you don't get question banned!). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I have the impression these questions are all a variation of the same. Moreover, if you'd actually fully reaize the power of the Group module, part of those questions might be solve-able ... using the Group module.

Comment: Actually i don't understand the group module. Basically i want a page where i can assign a permission rather than admin, another user which is created by admin have permission to assign the permissions to another users. The group module is quite confusing, i want a simple theme where a two dropdown is there and one can select  the user and other can select the permission as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible Look into [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

One can install the [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) module and set per user access control settings per content node.

> The ACL module, short for Access Control Lists, is an API for other
>   modules to create lists of users and give them access to nodes. It has
>   no UI of its own and will not do anything by itself; install this
>   module only if some other module tells you to.

Comment: This module is asking for rebuild permissions? what to do ?

Comment: Click on rebuild.

Comment: i want a user wise permissions like i have a role name ouroffice-user then under this i have a 10 users and i want to allocate different different permissions to these 10 users like no. 1 have a permission to update the welcome content and no. 2 have a permission to update the about us page all users belong to single role that ouroffice-user

Comment: Check the module documentation and configuration. You can get more details.