# Multi-site vs Large Single site for Intranet

Tags: entities, multi-sites

Whenever I look at "Should I use Multi-site?", it always seems to depend on the use case. (I am using Drupal 7)

I have been developing a company's Intranet on a single Drupal install and it is getting larger and larger.

I have about 75 Content Types and over 500 fields.

The reason for the Drupal site having so many Content Types is to give each department access to manage nodes within specific content types. (Using Content Access).

There are also additional Content Types for workflows that are using with Rules.

I feel the greatest performance hit when managing fields on a Content Type.
Other than that, the site still runs smoothly.

In a situation like this where there are going to be so many more fields and content types added, does it make sense to use Multi-site instead? Or is it perhaps the specs of my Server that are causing the slowness?

It is convenient having everything on one site since I can have a unified Dashboard, not have to re-make the User groups/roles on multiple sites, etc.

In this use case, is it worth converting my structure to a Multi-site setup?

Comment: which drupal version you are using?

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens. Thank you for your response. More information has been added as to why there are so many content types

Comment: Hi @zhilevan. I am using Drupal 7.54

Comment: Instead Of changing the structure I think you should  do some optimization on your content type and fields ( maybe you can implement wit more fewer content types or fields )  , and also try on the methods to increase your performance.

Comment: If a rebuild was as option, I'd re-use fields with the conditional fields module and a single pre-populated entity reference back to a home node for each department. Or a full blown Organic Groups solution with the same idea.

Comment: Hi @zhilevan - I will consider that!

Comment: Hello @NiallMurphy - Thank you for the suggestion. Since I am still in the early development stages, I will absolutely consider that. Using Conditional Fields for that may do it but perhaps OG may be best for my situation since it is for an Intranet with over 700 employees. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Yeah, in that case, OG is good. I managed to go from around 20 content types down to 3 for my OG content using Conditional fields. (2 of them are very heavy and rarely used).

Comment: I did it by creating one taxonomy vocabulary and many terms for all of the "psuedo content types".  Then I referenced the terms in an entity reference field and configured conditional fields. As an extra option, I used  https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate and built custom links using tokens/php around my site so teams never even see the entity reference field.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you may want to consider is to start using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections.

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various types of roles used by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

And because [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) also integrates with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, you could probably transform your workflows related rules toward [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) equivalents.

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".