# How to define profile types per group type in the Group module?

Tags: users, group

I am working on a site where I am just starting to work with the Drupal 7 version of the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. The groups and roles stuff is fine but can I define a profile type per group type?

eg. Group Type "School" might have profiles Principal, Teacher, Student, Volunteer and Group Type "Church" might have profiles Pastor, Youth Worker, Member etc

So when someone signs up I want them to find their group (eg St John's Baptist) and then enter their profile type (eg Pastor).

Then I want to show specific content depending on their profile type. eg All Pastor's will have access to certain nodes.

Group profile types seems to be global so looking for a way to do this neatly.

Answer (score 0):

> ... can I define a profile type per group type?

*Sure (yes?) you can*, it's what in the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module is called "**Group Specific Roles**".

> Group profile types seems to be global ...

Here you're talking about what in the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module is called "**Special Global Role**" or "**Configured Global Roles**".

For more details on this, refer to the answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197493/39516)".

Be aware: this answer applies to D7, as in the question (for D8 it would be different ...).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Can you explain the difference between a Group Role and a Group Member Profile Type? I thought the Profile Type would be useful as there is little difference I require between the different users (other than labelling really) but these seem to be global across all groups.