# How to restrict group node access to a user/member of an group?

Tags: nodes, group

I am using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module and I have created a group called "Group-Y" and group type "Group-type-Y". I also defined a group role name "Admin". Added an member with role "Admin".

I have checked this module, which provided the access based on page,

https://www.drupal.org/project/page_access

Page access module does work with global user admin, like here:

[image]

I tried to achieve it for group admin. In the edit node, page access settings are not displayed.

[image]

I need to achieve to restrict node based on user/role in a group. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Yes, am using the group module. I need to restrict the group node based on the user/role defined in group.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, for what you're trying to achieve, you do not need the "Page access" module. Instead only using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module it should be possible to get it to work.

Some basics about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module to be aware of:

- Make sure you enable `gnode`, a submodule of the Group module.
- For each group type you need to define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types.
- Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it (refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)" for more details about that).

It seems that you would want to grant access to what, in Group, is called "Members". But you woudn't allow access to "Anonymous" (site visitors that are not logged it). However, you also need to think about which access you want to give to "Outsiders" (=  logged in users who are not a member of a group).

With the above in place, it's just a matter of assigning a node to a Group. So if the `gnode` submodule is enabled, you should be able to do so via a group-related field that will be shown on the node edit form, via which you can then select the appropriate group

#### More info

Refer to "[How to create collections of content that can be accessed by users with various access levels?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/170)" for more  info about all this.

Comment: gnode is already enabled in my drupal 8. What i need to know is if i create an node in group module for ex. take it as **basic page**. after creation it will land in to the node page with url as [link](http://localhost/node/72). Am not sure 72 is an node id but i assumes it as node id. I need to restrict few members in group not to view this node. Could it be possible?

Comment: About the "*I need to restrict few members in group not to view this node*" (in your last comment): any kind of permission related to "a" group, applies to ALL members of that group. If for "some of the group members" you need another permission, then clearly something is wrong in your current configuration of your groups.

Comment: "any kind of permission related to "a" group, applies to ALL members of that group" yes i agree, it will applies to all members in group and it does happen like that. But i need to restrict one node for a section of members? How could i achieve it?