# role and permission

Tags: users

I want to create a new role and give that to some permissions but not for drupal access, it for my website to access some of things in drupalwebsite. Like student/parent/teacher/alumni etc.is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should give it a try to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module (available as of D7, and has a D8 version also). You'd enable the `gnode` submodule, and for each group type you would define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types.

From the details included in your question, it seems that possibly you'd only need 1 group type, with as many groups for that group type as you like/need. Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it (refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197493/39516)" for more details about that).

***More info:*** [What's the purpose of the Group module and how to get started with it?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/194)