# How can I assign a database for each user?

Tags: 8, database

I am new to Drupal and facing problems. I want to assign a database for each user where user can edit, delete or make entry to their database table.

For example I want to develop a database management system for doctors so that each doctor has their own patient database with scanned image of report, patient name, address, description, sex etc so that they can keep track of their patients. How can I implement it in Drupal 8?

Comment: You are obviously so new that the question is too broad to be answered precisely here in this neat Q&A format. You don't give every user their own database. You create a user role "Doctor", you create a node type "Patient", populate patients with fields, build some permissions and Views so that Doctors can create Patients but **only edit and view their own patients**. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module for this. [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

Some basics about he [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module to be aware of:

- Make sure you enable `gnode`, a submodule of the Group module.
- For each group type you need to define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types.
- Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it (refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197493/39516)" for more details about that).

With the appropriate permissions configured, it's just a matter of assigning a node to a Group: based on how you configured the roles and permissions, the Group module will allowed/deny access for any user.
Refer to "[How to create collections of content that can be accessed by users with various access levels?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/170)" for more  info about all this.

**Resources**

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".